# How to merge Shapefiles from multiple folders into Geodatabase Featureclass?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, esri-geodatabase, merge

I have a question regarding the merge of a lot of folders, which has a lot subfolders, which has the shapefiles stored. I would like to merge all those in one geodatabase. 
So I thought to use a Python script.

```
import os, arcpy.da

print os.getcwd()

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        current_dir =  os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
        arcpy.env.workspace = current_dir
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(".shp")
        Merge = r"D:\Test\Merge_multiple.gdb\Totals"
        for fc in fcList:
            print fc
            arcpy.Merge_management([fc,destination],Merge)
            arcpy.Delete_management(desination)
            arcpy.Rename_management(Merge, destination)
        break
```

So, I started the script and after a minute it stops and unfortunately, no result. Because there are several different names in the shapefiles, I thought to use only the suffix .shp.

Could you help me?

[Edit]
I get the path of the working directory in the python window. After this message, the window closes without any errors.
[image]

[Edit2]
Based on PolyGeo's advice, I've run the script also in the IDLE environment and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include what is printed back to your Python window when you run this script, please?  And also include any error messages that you may be receiving.

Comment: Have you tried running it from an IDE like IDLE which comes with Python?  That message looks like you have perhaps double-clicked on a *.py to execute it.

Comment: Yes, see the second Edit for the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy shapefiles from multiple folders into a single geodatabase, you could do this:

```
import arcpy
import os
ws = #path to input folder
dst = #path to output geodatabase
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(ws,datatype="FeatureClass"):
    for file in filenames:
      print file
      filepath = os.path.join(dirpath,file)
      outpath = os.path.join(dst,file[:-4]) #drops the .shp extension
      arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(filepath,outpath)
```

Comment: Using `os.path.splitext(file)[0]` or `file.split('.')[0]` instead of `file[:-4]` would allow this method to copy feature classes from geodatabases, while keeping their full name intact.

Comment: Well, that dit it! It's running now and the results are great. Thanks!